# Sum of two columns of 2 tables

Tags: list-manipulation

I have 3 tables ( which represents values of functions ) of the form:

```
 tb1={r, f1(r)}
 tb2={r, f2(r)}
 tb3={r, f3(r)}
```

I need to obtain a table of the form:

```
    tb4={r1,f1(r1)+f2(r1)+f3(r1)}
        {r2,f1(r2)+f2(r2)+f3(r2)}
               .
               .
               .
```

I think it should be pretty simple but I can not figure it out. Thanks in advance.

As an example, for r=0.1 , I have :

```
  tb1={0.1,78}
  tb2={0.1,-43}
  tb3={0.1,5}
```

for r=0.2:

```
  tb1={0.2,68}
  tb2={0.2,-41}
  tb3={0.2,4}
```

and so on in r=0.2,0.3... so I need to get

```
  tb4={0.1,78-43+5}
      {0.2,68-41+4}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of your tables, since you didn't provide one:

```
tb1 = Table[{r,f1[r]}, {r, {r1,r2,r3}}]
tb2 = Table[{r,f2[r]}, {r, {r1,r2,r3}}]
tb3 = Table[{r,f3[r]}, {r, {r1,r2,r3}}]
```

> {{r1, f1[r1]}, {r2, f1[r2]}, {r3, f1[r3]}}
>
> {{r1, f2[r1]}, {r2, f2[r2]}, {r3, f2[r3]}}
>
> {{r1, f3[r1]}, {r2, f3[r2]}, {r3, f3[r3]}}

You can use [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy) to get your desired output:

```
summary = GroupBy[Join[tb1, tb2, tb3], First->Last, Total]
```

> <|r1 -> f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1], r2 -> f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2], 
>    r3 -> f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]|>

If you don't like associations:

```
List @@@ Normal @ summary
```

> {{r1, f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1]}, {r2, f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2]}, {r3, 
>     f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]}}

Answer (score 2):

There are any number of ways you could go here depending on what your exact requirements are and where exactly you're starting from. If you're not absolutely constrained to start with your `tb1,..., tb3` lists, you can define

```
tbthrough[r_] := {r, Through[(f1 + f2 + f3)[r]]}
```

or

```
tbsum[r_] := {r, Sum[f[r], {f, {f1, f2, f3}}]}
```

Then both of these

```
tbthrough /@ {r1, r2, r3, r4}
tbsum /@ {r1, r2, r3, r4}
```

produce

```
(* {{r1, f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1]}, 
    {r2, f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2]}, 
    {r3, f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]}, 
    {r4, f1[r4] + f2[r4] + f3[r4]}} *)
```

Or, if you can put your lists `tb1,..., tb3` into one meta-list, `tb`,

```
tblist[r_] := {r, #[r]} & /@ {f1, f2, f3}

tb = tblist /@ {r1, r2, r3, r4}

(* {{{r1, f1[r1]}, {r1, f2[r1]}, {r1, f3[r1]}}, 
    {{r2, f1[r2]}, {r2, f2[r2]}, {r2, f3[r2]}}, 
    {{r3, f1[r3]}, {r3, f2[r3]}, {r3, f3[r3]}}, 
    {{r4, f1[r4]}, {r4, f2[r4]}, {r4, f3[r4]}}} *)
```

Then

```
{#[[1, 1, 1]], Total @@ #[[;; , ;; , 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[tb, First]
```

Edit: You could also define `tb = Join[tb1, tb2, tb3]` (so, losing a level compared to `tb` created above), and then use the modified

```
{#[[1, 1]], Total@#[[;; , 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[tb, First]
```

Both of these yield

```
(* {{r1, f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1]}, 
    {r2, f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2]},
    {r3, f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]}, 
    {r4, f1[r4] + f2[r4] + f3[r4]}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One more thing, how can I make the sum if what I have are numbers?

Comment: If your `f`s are well-defined functions and `f[r]` is a number then `Total`, `Sum`, `Through` and whatever will all work as you'd expect. So you shouldn't have to change a thing to get them working.

Comment: Sorry but it is not working. I have 3 lists of numbers, no more. I do not have the functions, just the results of evaluations of three functions in 200 points . I want to sum the result of those evaluation , I mean, sum the second column of the  three tables in each point, for example: for r=0.1 , I get the respective value in each table. I want a new table that is the sum of those three values for r=0.1 and so on with r=0.2,0.3,0.4...., I'm sorry if I have not been clear , just thought that the solution to my problem was general :D

Comment: Ah, okay. If you don't have the functions then {#[[1, 1]], Total@#[[;; , 2]]} & /@ GatherBy[Join[tb1, tb2, tb3], First]` should work. (Slightly modified from my answer.)

Comment: Thank you very much; you help me a lot ! Now I will go to understand the code for future calculations :D . Thank you again :D

Answer (score 1):

Answer (not optimized) only based on the question statement:

```
list = {r1, r2, r3};
tb = Table[{list[[i]], ToExpression["f" <> ToString[i] <> "[r]"]}, {i,
1, Length[list]}]
```

prints:

```
{{r1, f1[r]}, {r2, f2[r]}, {r3, f3[r]}}
```

Then,

```
tbfinal = Table[{list[[i]],Sum[tb[[j]][[2]] /. r -> list[[i]], {j, 1,Length[list]}]}, {i, 1, Length[list]}]
```

prints:

```
{{r1, f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1]}, {r2, f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2]}, {r3, f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Merge

You can also use `Merge[Total]` on the list of tables converted to `Association`s.

Using @Carl's setup

```
tb1 = Table[{r, f1[r]}, {r, {r1, r2, r3}}];
tb2 = Table[{r, f2[r]}, {r, {r1, r2, r3}}];
tb3 = Table[{r, f3[r]}, {r, {r1, r2, r3}}];
```

Convert the list of tables into a list of `Association`s:

```
assoc = Association/@(Rule@@@#&/@{tb1,tb2,tb3});
```

`Merge[Total]` the associations and convert back to `List`:

```
List @@@ Normal @ Merge[Total][assoc]
```

> {{r1, f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1]}, {r2, f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2]}, {r3, 
>         f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]}}

Alternatively, define `mergeTotal` to compose all the steps in to a single one:

```
mergeTotal = Composition[List @@@ # &, Normal , Merge[Total]];
mergeTotal[assoc]
```

> {{r1, f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1]}, {r2, f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2]}, {r3, 
>         f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]}}

## Total + Through + Map

```
funcs = {f1, f2, f3};
vars = {r1, r2, r3};
{#, Total @ Through @ funcs @ #} & /@ vars
```

> {{r1, f1[r1] + f2[r1] + f3[r1]}, {r2, f1[r2] + f2[r2] + f3[r2]}, {r3, 
>         f1[r3] + f2[r3] + f3[r3]}}